# Add element in list inside function body, then return

Tags: c++

Given the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

class test{
    public:
    int t = 34;
};

std::list<test> list;

void func(){
    test t;
    list.push_back(t);
}

int main(){
    func();
    std::cout<<list.front().t<<std::endl;
}
```

It prints `34`. Given that `list.push_back(test &ref)` is called (so the parameter is not copied), why does the object remains even after the exit of the function?

Comment: why do you think `push_back` doesn't copy the object (it does)?

Comment: I was very sure that internally list added the reference itself, but you're right my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.push_back(test &ref)` doesn't mean that the reference is stored. For containers, all elements are copied/moved, or construct in place.

Why does the object remain even after the exit of the function?
The remained value is a copy.

See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back):

> ```cpp
> void push_back( const T& value ); (1)  
> void push_back( T&& value );(2)    (since C++11)
> ```
>
> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1. The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
> 2. value is
>    moved into the new element. No iterators or references are
>    invalidated.